# How we can display data from array on blade page

Tags: laravel

I have written this code

**app\Http\Controller\processController.php**

```
class ProcessController extends BaseController {
    public function getData()
    {
        $data['data']=DB::table('process_table')->get();
        if(count($data) > 0)
        {            
            return view('process',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            return view('process');   
        }

    } }
```

**route\web.php**

```
Route::get('/process', 'processController@getData');
```

**resources\views\process.blade.php**

What should i write here in blade file and how to print `$data` values in table format ??

Comment: What are the names of the rows that your process_table has?

Comment: There is no problem here that you are trying to resolve besides learning how to use laravel.  Please read the Laravel Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Answer (score 4):

The key values of your array are the names of the variables you can use in your view. So, in your case `$data` will contain all rows from the table `process_table`.

To make sure that the variable exists, you can use the `isset` function.

Now you can do this for example:

```
@if (isset($data))
    <ul>
        @foreach ($data as $row)
            <li>{{ $row->name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: it show error"Undefined property: stdClass::$name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\demoProject\resources\views\process.blade.php)"

Comment: @Jerodev is assuming that you have a property called `name` in your `$row`. replace `name` with whatever is the content of each datum in your array.

Comment: Indeed, just like @darthaditya noted, you have to replace `name` with a column that is available in you database table.

Comment: Glad I could help! Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might also find this.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply dump it

```
@if (isset($data))
    {{{ json_encode($data) }}}
@endif
```

Comment: Yeah this is woking but how we can display it in table format

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**app\Http\Controller\processController.php**

```
class ProcessController extends BaseController {
    public function getData()
    {
        $data['data']=DB::table('process_table')->get();
        if(count($data) > 0)
        {            
            return view('process',compact('data'));
        }
        else
        {
            return view('process');   
        }

    } 
}
```

**resources\views\process.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <h1 style="color: purple;"><center><b>Process Data</b></center></h1>
    <hr>
    @if(isset($data))
      <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane tab-margin table-area-margin active" id="profile">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table payment-info-tbl">
                <tr class="displaying-passages-title">
                  <th>Your Field</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach ($data as $datas)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{$datas->yourField}}</td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach

              </table>
            </div>
          </div><!--tab panel profile-->
      </div><!--tab content-->
    @else
      <h1>No Data</h1>
    @endif



  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you lookin for this:

```
@if (isset($data))
<table>

    @foreach ($data as $key => $row)
        <tr>
           <td>{{ $key }}</td>
           <td>{{ (is_array($row)) ? json_encode($row) : $row }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
@endif
```